# Como mostrar los grupos de permisos de un item dentro de una lista de Sharepoint Online con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lista, permisos, sharepoint-online

Tengo una lista de Sharepoint Online, a los items le rompieron la herencia y necesito mostrarlos con su respectivos grupo de permisos dentro de una tabla en una pagina en blanco de Sharepoint.

En el siguiente código muestro el grupo de permisos que tiene la lista en general,

Me puede ayudar a realizar el mismo procedimiento pero por cada uno de los items

Saludos

```
function getListPerms() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext;
            var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
            var site = clientContext.get_web();
            listSecurableObject = site.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
            listRoleAssignments = listSecurableObject.get_roleAssignments();



clientContext.load(listRoleAssignments,'Include(Member)');

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListPerms_onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListPerms_onQueryFailed));
   }

nction getListPerms() {
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext;
                var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
                var site = clientContext.get_web();
                listSecurableObject = site.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");
                listRoleAssignments = listSecurableObject.get_roleAssignments();

                clientContext.load(listRoleAssignments,'Include(Member)');



 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListPerms_onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.getListPerms_onQueryFailed));
           }
function getListPerms_onQuerySucceeded() {
            var listPerms="";
            listPerms += '<table border="1">';
            listPerms += '<tr>';
            listPerms += '<td align="center">ID</td>';
            listPerms += '</tr>';
            var listPermsEnumerator =  this.listRoleAssignments.getEnumerator();
            //var listPermsEnumerator =  this.listSecurableObject.getEnumerator();
            while (listPermsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var rAssignment = listPermsEnumerator.get_current();
                listPerms += '<tr>';
                listPerms += '<td align="center">' + rAssignment.get_member().get_loginName() +  '</td>';
                listPerms += '</tr>';
                console.log(rAssignment.get_member());
            }
            listPerms += '</table>';
            document.getElementById('listPermsTable').innerHTML = listPerms;
            console.log(listPerms);
       }
       function getListPerms_onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
           alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
       }
```

Saludos

Comment: te recomiendo leer [ask] pues tu pregunta es muy amplia y por lo tanto terminaría cerrada saludos

Comment: gracias @AlfredoPaz por tu comentario espero y con la modificación que le hice pueda se un poco mas legible Saludos